# How to use LightDM in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, lightdm

I really like Oneiric's log in screen, and I would like to get it for Lucid. Can someone help show me how?

Thank you,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

According the this tutorial you can easily do it.
http://www.dreamingisdigital.com/2011/05/20/install-lightdm-on-ubuntu/